# How to intercept form submits reliably?

Tags: jquery, onsubmit

I'm trying to intercept all kind of form submissions for a specifc form on a web page. It looks to be very simple with jQuery: `form.submit(function(e) {…})` and it works beautifully if I click the submit button.

However there is also an onChange property on a select field which does `this.form.submit()` and it looks like this call circumvents my listener (in Chromium/Firefox):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitForm(e) {
        window.alert('submitted');
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#bar').submit(submitForm);
    });
</script>

<form id="bar">
    <select name="name" onChange="this.form.submit()">
        <option>Foo</option>
        <option>Bar</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Obviously in the code above I could just change `this.form.submit()` to a specific reference of my submit listener. However in my real app it's not that simple so I'm looking for way where I don't have to modify the onChange property.

If I did not do a stupid mistake but this is actually expected browser behavior, I'd be really glad if you could explain the event flow and why this leads to the symptoms described above.

Comment: Oh, forgot to mention that "$('#bar').submit()" for the onChange part works as well. Does JS perform some kind of 'early-bind' on onX attributes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Calling the `form.submit()` method does not trigger the `submit` event, just like e.g. setting the `value` of a text box does not trigger its `change` event. Try to trigger the `submit` event through jQuery instead:

```
<form id="bar">
    <select name="name" onChange="$('#bar').submit();">
        <option>Foo</option>
        <option>Bar</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

According to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/submit/), the default `submit` action on the form will be fired and the form will be submitted.

Comment: Here is a drop-in replacement for onchange that doesn't require knowing the form id: `onchange="$(this.form).submit()"`