# Add an event handler to any normal web request

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit, form-submit

I have a timer running on my page that refreshes it every minute. There is also a search function on this page. Now say the search function takes 10 seconds to run when there are only 5 seconds left before the page refreshes - it ends up refreshing anyway and the search results are lost.

I'm wondering if there's a way to generically hook into an outgoing web request and in that cancel my refresh timer. I know for [AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202296/add-a-hook-to-all-ajax-requests-on-a-page) methods you can setup a global event handler, is there a way to do this for normal form submits like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957696/jquery-how-to-intercept-form-submits-reliably) but more generically - not having to hook into each form manually?